# cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Tags: c#, multithreading

Using *Example 1: Creating, starting, and interacting between threads* on this [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating) more specificaly line 3 to line 7 in the `Main()`

I have the following code with the following error:

> cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type
>   name instead.

**Program.cs**

```
public static ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
private static Thread testingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadTest.testThread()));
static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

**ThreadTest.cs**

```
public static void testThread()
{
}
```

Comment: So did you follow trying the advice given in the compiler error? Why do you want an instance of `threadTest` anyway?

Comment: Example 1: Creating, starting, and interacting between threads   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx#vcwlkthreadingtutorialexample1creating more specificaly line 3 to line 7 in the Main()

Comment: Right. Now look at your `testThread` method, and look at the example's `Alpha.Beta` method, look at the difference, and look at the error message again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100009/member-method-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `testThread` is a static method, so it's available via type name. So, instead of using isntance `threadTest`, use `ThreadTest` type.

```
// public static void testThread()
testingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadTest.testThread));
```

Or change method declaration (remove `static`):

```
// public void testThread()
testingThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadTest.testThread));
```

Also you should pass method to delegate `ThreadTest.testThread` (parentheses removed) instead of passing result of method invokation `ThreadTest.testThread()`.