# UWP Button visibility property not visible

Tags: c#, uwp, controls

I cannot set the Button.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed on any of my buttons.

Below is the xaml

```
           <Button x:Name="createPageButton" Content="Create Page" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="740,75,0,0" Height="61" Width="175" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" Click="CreatePageButton_Click" />
        <Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1699,705,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

In my code behind I try to set the Visibility property.

```
            TestButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

I get the following error msg.

Error   CS0176  Member 'Visibility.Visible' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce your issue with your code above. It worked well on my side with invoking it for example, inside the click event handle.

```
private void CreatePageButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
}
```

My UWP app version is target build 15063.

> Error CS0176 Member 'Visibility.Visible' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

But for this error, it seems like you are trying to access static members with instance syntax which is not allowed.  Details please reference [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545346/cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference-qualify-it-with-a-type-name-inste). If you still have issues please upload a minimal reproduced project.

Updated:

If you are using the [WindowsTemplateStudio](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio), by default in the template studio blank app, the page doesn't reference the `Windows.UI.Xaml` namespace (which `Visibility` class is belong to), so that thrown this error. Just add this reference it will work well.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
```

Comment: I created a blank UWP test project using the Template Studio blank template and I get the CS0176 error in the Button_click event.  But if I usethe UWP blank template with no Template Studio and add a button click, I can see the TestButton.Visibility.=Visibility.Collapsed work. hmm,  Other Template Studio apps don't work.

Comment: @TreyBalut I tested, by default in template studio blank app, the page doesn't reference the `Windows.UI.Xaml` so that thrown this error, I will update the answer.

Comment: Sunteen, Thanks, I added the using Windows.UI.Xaml and it works.  A bug in the Template Studio methinks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the cause was due to a conflict in the imports / using namespaces. It seems that I had two namespaces which have the same naming.

To fix this issue, I had to specify the exact class reference: System.Windows.Visibility