# Cannot set the Z index on static member

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

I am having a similar issue to this post: [Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100009/member-method-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference) but the answer didn't provide me with a solution.

I have a simple  within a  and I want to use the static method SetZIndex to alter that value so that each circle, when clicked on, will appear top.

The xaml is here...

```
<Window x:Class="Canvas.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Canvas x:Name="Circles">
    <Ellipse x:Name="Circle_Blue" Fill="Blue" Canvas.Top="25" Canvas.Left="25" Height="100" Width="100" MouseDown="Circle_Blue_MouseDown"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Circle_Red" Fill="Red" Height="100" Width="100" MouseDown="Circle_Red_MouseDown"></Ellipse>
    <Ellipse x:Name="Circle_Green" Fill="Green" Canvas.Left="50" Height="100" Width="100" MouseDown="Circle_Green_MouseDown"></Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

This is the line of code that is generating the following error: 'System.Windows.Window' does not contain a definition for 'SetZIndex' and no extension method 'SetZIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Window' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
    int Circle_Blue_index = 1;
    int Circle_Red_index = 2;
    int Circle_Green_index = 3;

    private void Circle_Green_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Circle_Blue_index != 3)
            Circle_Blue_index = 3;

        if (Circle_Red_index != 1)
            Circle_Red_index = Circle_Red_index -=1;

        if (Circle_Green_index != 1)
            Circle_Green_index = Circle_Green_index -=1;

        Canvas.MainWindow.GetWindow(Circles).SetZIndex(Circle_Blue, Circle_Blue_index);   
    }
```

I have tried to use the syntax ClassName.Control.Property but it would appear I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your namespace is "Canvas" is causing that to take precedence - i.e. "Canvas." is seen as trying to reference a type in your Canvas namespace and not a member of the [System.Windows.Controls.Canvas class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.aspx). Doing something like the following should work:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Canvas.SetZIndex(Circle_Blue, Circle_Blue_index);
```