# Static member instance reference issue

Tags: c#, static-methods

I have the following static method held in an Analytics class:

```
 public static void buttonHit(string eventName, string eventAction, string description)
{
    gua.sendEventHit(eventName,eventAction,description,1);
}
```

In a second class I'm trying to fill this out as follows:

```
Analytics analytics;
void buttonEventAnalytic()
{   
   analytics.buttonHit(event_NameString, event_ActionString, event_Label);  
}
```

However when I do so I get the following error:

> error CS0176: Static member `Analytics.buttonHit(string, string, string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead

Could someone please enlighten me as to how I can defeat this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `class` name instead of instance. Static members are supposed to be accessed with class name.

```
Analytics.buttonHit(event_NameString, event_ActionString, event_Label);
```

> A static function member (method, property, event, operator, or
>   constructor) does not operate on a specific instance, and it is a
>   compile-time error to refer to this in such a function member, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645629%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

use directly

```
Analytics.buttonHit(event_NameString, event_ActionString, event_Label);
```

because static member are not related to object they are associated with class only

Comment: That's C++ notation. Use `.` instead of `::` in C#.