# Updating each Item in a list

Tags: c#, list, xna, xna-4.0

So, I've created a list with 2 objects in. I want to make sure they both update.

```
public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    Player.Update(gameTime);
    Seagull.Update(gameTime);
    foreach (Seagull seagull in seagulls)
    {
        seagull.Update(gameTime);//Here is where the error is. 
    }
}
```

This is the error observed [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tusld.png)

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: I've updated my Question with a screen shot of the error.

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100009/member-method-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference) help? It was the first result in Google, and suggests that your `Seagull.Update()` method is static. Perhaps you didn't mean for that method to be static?

Comment: It's preferable to include the error text in the question rather than linking to a screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

the error tells us that `seagull.Update` is a static method, which means it can't be called for each seagull, only for 'seagulls' as a whole. I suspect you don't want this, and will need to stop it being a static method (by removing the `static` keyword).

For more information on static methods: [What's a "static method" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124102/whats-a-static-method-in-c)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: Thanks. This turned out to be the issue.

Comment: Not a problem. Feel free to mark this as the answer (using the tick below the voting buttons)