# Access to the property from MainViewModel (WPF, C#)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have class FrontModel contains some fields from XAML:

```
public class FrontModel()
{
  public static string LoginName { get; set;}
  public static string userPass;
  public static string Domain { get; set;}
}
```

Into ViewModel I'm try to connect to FrontModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
  FrontModel fm = new FrontModel();

  public MainViewModel()
  {
   ...
   fm.LoginName = Environment.UserName.ToString();//error
  }  
}
```

But I don't have access to my field. What I'm doing here wrong?

[image]

I know that `LoginName {get; set;}` can do directly into MainViewModel and then it's working, but I'm trying to move it to separate class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100009/member-method-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference)

Comment: As a hint, try to google next time for error message, removing private parts. There are typically several questions on SO for each error message already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are referencing a `static` property on a non static instance of FrontModel. Try:

```
FrontModel.LoginName = Environment.UserName.ToString();
```

Or if the property does not need to be static, remove `static`.

Comment: ok, it's no possible to use alias to my class? (like into my example fm)

Comment: no you can't use `fm.LoginName` because `LoginName` is static, reading this post should clear things up for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795502/what-is-the-use-of-static-variable-in-c-when-to-use-it-why-cant-i-declare-th