# Error when trying to call another class method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call another class but get the error CS0176:

> Member 'Player.MyMethod()' cannot be accessed with an instance
>   reference; qualify it with a type name instead

What does the error message mean exactly? I thought this was how I created a C# class object/instance.

Code:

```
using System;

namespace Examples
{
    public class Player
    {
        public static void MyMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello!");
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var myObject = new Player();

            myObject.MyMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100023/9891285 had the answer, sorry! I removed the static-part of `MyMethod()`.

Comment: MyMethod() is a static function so its call with class name

Player.MyMethod()

or you can remove static

Comment: Remove the static from `MyMethod()`