# Memeber 'Model.Fields' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; quailfy it with a type name instead

Tags: c#

I have added a list in my model like so:

```
    public static List<string> Fields
    {
        get
        {
           var results = new List<string>() { "Name", "Date", "Address", "..." };
            return results;

        }
    }
```

When I try to access my list in my method I get the following error:
"Memeber 'Model.Fields' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; quailfy it with a type name instead"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Member '<method>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100009/member-method-cannot-be-accessed-with-an-instance-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `Fields` is static, if you do something like this:

```
MyClass test = new MyClass();
```

you don't access `Fields` using `test`, instead you use the class name - `MyClass`:

```
//wrong
test.Fields

//right
MyClass.Fields
```