# error CS0176: Member 'Camera.main.current' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a instance of a GameObject at the position of the mouse when LeftMouseButton is pressed ,im trying to convert it to world position  but i get a error : Member 'Camera.main.current' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

```
public GameObject tower;  
   public Camera sceneCamera;
   Vector3 objectP;   
    void Update () 
     {
        sceneCamera = Camera.main;
        if (sceneCamera!= null) 
        {
            Vector3 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
         mousePos.z = 2.0f;
        Vector3 objectP = Camera.main.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        }
         
     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
         {
         Instantiate(tower,objectP, Quaternion.identity);
         }
     }
    
   
}
```

Comment: `Camera.current` is a static reference to the current camera.  Instead use `Camera.main` which is the instance of the main camera.  You get the error because you are trying to access a static property of the type Camera, which cannot be accessed using an instance of a camera.  [Camera.current](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-current.html)  vs [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html)

Comment: Via [`Camera.main` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) and [`ScreenToWorldPoint()` documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html): `Camera.main.current.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos)` should be `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Member '<member name>' cannot be accessed with an instance reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1100009/1092820)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Camera.main.current` with `Camera.main`.

`main` and `current` are both static properties of the `Camera` class, so it doesn't make sense to chain them like you're doing (and is, in fact, disallowed).

Comment: `Camera.current` should not be used in this situation.  From docs `for low-level render control only`

Comment: You're right, I edited the answer.